# proliant 380gl g5 raid drive rebuilt but leds are both lit bright green

Tags: hp, raid5, hp-smart-array

After replacing a failed Raid 5 146gig SAS drive in logical drive 2 yesterday the system reports all is good but the LEDs on the front of the drive are both on and the one on the left is bright green. Any thoughts? and both lit LEDs are green.

Comment: so when you say the system reports all is good is this looking at via the hp array manager?

Answer (score 0):

Healthy drives should display green lights in a Smart Array controller setup.